# how to give array index a named key on runtime

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xml, xml-serialization

Here i am trying to use XMLSerializer class to convert data from mysql table into an xml file.I want the xml file to be like this

[image]

For this ,i need to change the numeric indexes into 'book'.Currently i can generate an array of the following form:It has numeric indexing ,but for my purpose both of the indexes (0 and 1) have to be 'book'.

[image]

How  can i change both the numeric indexes to be 'book'??

FULL CODE:

```
   include('XMLSerializer/XML/Serializer.php');
   $host='localhost';
   $user='root';
   $pass='';
   $db='xmlserializer';

   $dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);
   $sql='SELECT lname,fname FROM employee';
   $sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);
   $sth->execute();

   $xml=array('library'=>array());

   $i=0;
   while($result=$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       array_push($xml['library'],$result);

   }
   print_r($xml);
   $serializer=new XML_Serializer();


   $result=$serializer->serialize($xml);
   if($result===true){
      file_put_contents('myxml.xml',$serializer->getSerializedData());
   }
```

Comment: If your 2 keys become "book", they will be overriden... Do you wish keys like ["book1"], ["book2"] ? or you want one more dimension to be ["library"]["book"][0] ?

Comment: i can manage what you suggested but to get the desired xml format both of them have to be book.

Comment: The problem is that you can't have an array like `array("book" => array(...), "book" => array(...))`, so you should better create separate arrays, one for each book, and then generate your xml for each array...

Comment: i  know they will override each onther.But still can't figure out an alternative way :(

Comment: As I said, you'll have to generate the xml of each book separately, or you have to change your hierarchy as @ericMartinez suggested...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `default tag` in you `XML_Serializer`:

So your code should be:

```
$options = array(
      "defaultTagName"  => "book",
);

$serializer = new XML_Serializer($options);
```

Check this link for more information : https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.xml.xml-serializer.xml-serializer.examples.php